# SQLAlchemy does not create Foreign keys on MySQL [Debian Linux]

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, debian, constraints

For same code snippet, SQLAlchemy creates Foreign Key constraint on Mac OX, however, it fails to create foreign key constraint on Debian Linux.

**Environment & Libraries:**

Python 2.7

SQLAlchemy 0.7.8

MySQL-python-1.2.3 [This is the connector, and I am suspecting something is wrong here]

**Code Snippet:**

```
class PRStatusCV(globalBase):

    __tablename__ = 'pr_status_cv'
    pr_status_cv_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name            = Column(VARCHAR(100), nullable=False, unique=True)

    def __init__(self, id, name, desc):
        self.pr_status_cv_id = id
        self.name            = name
        self.description     = desc



class PhysicalRun(globalBase):

    __tablename__ = 'prs'
    pr_id       = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    run_name              = Column(VARCHAR(200), nullable=False, unique=True)
    pr_status_cv_id       = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('pr_status_cv.pr_status_cv_id'))

    def __init__(self, name, status):
        self.run_name              = name
        self.pr_status_cv_id       = status
```

**In Debian Linux, the table created contains:**

```
CREATE TABLE `prs` (
  `pr_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `run_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `pr_status_cv_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pr_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `run_name` (`run_name`),
  KEY `pr_status_cv_id` (`pr_status_cv_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

**In Mac OSX the table created looks like this:**

```
CREATE TABLE `prs` (
  `pr_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `run_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `pr_status_cv_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pr_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `run_name` (`run_name`),
  KEY `pr_status_cv_id` (`pr_status_cv_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `prs_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`pr_status_cv_id`) REFERENCES `pr_status_cv` (`pr_status_cv_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Observation:
Seems like for Mac OSX SQLAlchemy chose InnoDB DB Engine by default, and MyISAM is chosen for Debian. Any idea why this is happening so?

What modifications do I need to make to have constraint - `` CONSTRAINT `prs_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`pr_status_cv_id`) REFERENCES `pr_status_cv` ``, instead of just `` KEY `pr_status_cv_id` (`pr_status_cv_id`) ``?

Is anything incorrect with my Debian Python deploy?

Comment: Fix your code snippets, they aren't readable.

Comment: MyIsam don't have constrains, so you need to fix the engine problem so solve the key problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ENGINE=MyISAM` MyISAM dosn't have Foreign Keys

add `__table_args__ = {'mysql_engine':'InnoDB'}` to get InnoDB insted

Comment: Thanks Puggan. I added __table_args__={'mysql_engine':'InnoDB'} and it seems to create the tables with the constraint.

Answer (score 0):

The [`default-storage-enginge`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_default-storage-engine) is most likely set differently across the two systems.  Also have a look at [option-files](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/option-files.html) for how to configure this option.  Ideally, you should not be leaving this to the default; use the `mysql_engine` option in `Table()` to force it on mysql connections.